# Does a variable know of the array its in?

Tags: ruby

If a variable is inside an array, can you find this array just from that variable? Or does the variable have no knowledge of the data structure it's inside?

Just wondering if the following is possible (the only pseudo code is `v`'s `its_array` method):

```
array = [:a, :b]
array.object_id #=> 11709100 
array_from_inside = []
array.map do |v|
    v.its_array.object_id #=> 11709100 11709100
    array_from_inside = v.its_array #=> [:a, :b] [:a, :b]
end
array_from_inside.object_id #=> 11709100
array_from_inside #=> [:a, :b]
```

Comment: I'm guessing no.  What would `its_array` return if `v` was in multiple arrays?

Comment: @Armand, your point of a variable being in multiple arrays is worthwhile, but please refrain from guessing.  SO is intended to be authoritative. Guesses just take up space.

Comment: how do people even come up with such questions?

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the tip.  I wouldn't have guessed that comments were meant to be authoritative.

Comment: ...or questions or general comments. I just don't think guessing is useful.

Comment: ...or clever witticisms, puns--anything amusing. I'm all for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't put variables in arrays. You put objects in arrays, and variables aren't objects in Ruby, so you cannot put them in arrays. In fact, since variables aren't objects in Ruby, you pretty much cannot do *anything* with them. Ruby is an object-oriented language, whenever you want to do something with or to something, you do it by either calling a method on the thing or passing the thing as an argument to a method. But you can only call methods on objects and you can only pass objects as arguments, and variables aren't objects, so you really cannot do any of that. You can do exactly two things with variables: assign them and dereference them.

Secondly, no, in general, an object does not and *must not* know about any container it is put into. That would more or less negate the whole point of containers: that you can put arbitrary objects into them.

Plus, what would `its_array` even return for an object that is in no array? Or that is in two arrays? Or that is in an array which is in an array which is in an array?